# RealVNC GPO Install not showing in systray

Tags: vncserver, realvnc

Have installed RealVNC 6.3.2 on a test PC using the GPO Computer Configuration.

However when it is deployed to the test machine, I can see VNC Server in the start menu (doesn't produce any dialog box when clicked on), cannot see a VNC Server icon in the notification area/systray, and when trying to connect get "The connection was refused by the computer", which according to https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/connect-error-ref.html#connect-error-ref infers that the server isn't running (despite services.msc stating it is) or it is listening on the wrong port. Unless I am missing something, without the notification area/systray icon for RealVNC, I cannot check on which port it is configured to listen on.

My assumption is that VNC has been installed on some system account, and hence the GUI is appearing on a different console. Though the install docs didn't mention any issue with deploying to PCs, Users, or both.

Anyone know what is going here?

Comment: Which version of the RealVNC server are you running?

Comment: @srk - Updated question with version no. as requested.

Comment: Are you physically in front of the desktop with the problem, or are you using a different remote access tool like Microsoft's Remote Desktop (RDP)?

Comment: Desktop is in the same building, but I RDP'd into it when I logged in. Hopefully you're not saying that Windows doesn't run the same login process when RDP'ng as opposed to logging in locall?

Comment: Yes that is the case, you won't see the VNC Server (or any of its UI) in your RDP session as it only tracks the console session (i.e. what the local user would see). The server is probably running (as that is the default when it installs) but if you haven't added a subscription/license key then you won't be able to connect to it.

Comment: I think the license is what is missing here, now that you mention it. I have RDP'd into machines with licensed RealVNC installed before and been able to interact with it in ways I can't with this unlicensed install (because of course non-commercial users would never need to remote into another PC, in let's say, their home...)